# Binding to parent datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

My code behind as follows

```
this.DataContext = MainWindowViewModel.Instance;
```

xaml that I tried

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
    Visibility="{Binding RepairHasNoVendors, 
    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}"/>
```

My error

```
Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Vendors' property not found on 'object' 
''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Vendors; DataItem='MainWindow' 
(Name='')
```

As I understand, I've set my window datacontext in codebehind and I thought that by specifying relaticesource to be window I'd have access to those properties?

My viewmodel has that property

```
public ObservableCollection<VendorViewModel> Vendors
```

I also wanted to add that my combobox is inside datagridtemplatecolumn whos datacontext is set properly and I'm able to access those properties, for example my datagrid has datagridtextcolumn and binding works on it

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Repair Id" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding RepairID}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to a property of window's `datacontext` not the `window`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Vendors, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
    Visibility="{Binding RepairHasNoVendors, 
    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}" />
```

Comment: Rookie mistake on my part I should have known Path property wasnt written correctly. Thank you.